# How to order by date and add some randomness?

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way to sort by let's say date and add some randomness ?
[SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ea971/1)

I want to somehow sort them in a way that would get something like this:
Date:

```
02-12-2012
01-12-2012
04-12-2012
03-12-2012
```

Is there a way to do that with just sql without adding a new column ? Or is better to do it with php somehow?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you mean by "some randomness" & how it differs from "randomness"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a random number of days to the value:

```
select r.*
from random r
order by date + interval rand() * 5 day;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27a27d/1) is a *working* SQL Fiddle.

Your code stores the date as a string and uses non-standard date formats.  Both of these are practices that you should learn to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to sort on some randomness then you can try the following:

```
select * from random order by rand(), date;
```